# Android stream AWS S3 MP4 to SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, video-streaming

How can I stream MP4's from my S3 bucket into a SurfaceView through a MediaPlayer in Java for Android?

I currently have this code and it's not showing any video, it's just black, even though the URI is correct:

```
// GET PROPERTIES OF THE FRAME IN THE XML VIEW's
final SurfaceView surfaceViewFrame = (SurfaceView) llShowDrop.findViewById(R.id.camerapreview); 

final SurfaceHolder holder = surfaceViewFrame.getHolder();
holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
       @Override
       public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
           try {
               String object_key = this.getString(R.string.video) + "/" + ud.getFileName();

               AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(HelperAws.getCredentialsProvider());
               GeneratePresignedUrlRequest request = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(this.getString(R.string.public_bucket), object_key);
               URL objectURL = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(request);
               String url = objectURL.toString();

               player = new MediaPlayer();
               player.setDisplay(holder);
               player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(url));
               player.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
               player.setLooping(true);

               player.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                   @Override
                   public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                       mp.stop(); 
                       return false;
                   }
               });

               player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                       if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
                           player.start(); 
                       }
                   }
               });

               player.prepare();

           } catch (Exception e) { 
               stopPlayer();
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            Log.i(Helpers.TAG, "SURFACE CHANGED");
       }

       @Override
       public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
           Log.i(Helpers.TAG, "SURFACE DESCTROYED"); 
       }
   }

);
```

Comment: I think you may missing an expiry time on your signed URL.

Comment: The flow seems right. The presigned url is suspicious. Can you print the presigned url and load it in a web browser?

Comment: Yangfan, if I copy the url String into a browser it plays the video, so the URL is correct.  .prepare works and I don't get any errors on player.start(); either, but the video doesn't show in the SurfaceView, no audio either. The SurfaceView is visible, It plays a video from my device if I change the url String to point to a video on my device, it just doesn't seem to stream a video through a url

Comment: Are you able to stream any video in MediaPlayer? Does the app have internet permission? Does the video have correct file extension or mime type?

Comment: not able to stream yet, it's still just black!  the app does have internet permission and the video is mp4 and the code above is what is used to try and play it

Comment: @Nickmccomb Are you able to solve this?

Comment: @user2028 i did back then but can't remember what i did to fix it, sorry!